# How to specify .NET Core Linux dll name on Compile/Publish

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu-16.04

Running Ubuntu 16.04.1. When I compile or run dotnet publish, the dll just uses the name of the folder that the code is in. I would like it to force a specific name on the dll, in Visual Studio on Windows I would be able to do this by specifying the assembly name, but I'm not sure how to do it on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `project.json` file, you can add the following (or append the `outputName` field to the `buildOptions` section if it already exists)

```
"buildOptions": {
   "outputName": "{YourDllName}"    
 }
```